# How to get the URL of the first YouTube video from a search?

Tags: php, video, youtube

I have a site with movie sheets and I would like to display the movie's trailer.
In order to do that is it possible to get the URL of the top YouTube video from a YouTube search?

Since typing "[movie name] trailer" works well most of the time and the trailer is usually the top video, it would be easy.

On a different topic, what is the best way to let users modify the video if the picked one is not correct? With a voting system so it would need at least 4-5 votes in order for the video to be changed.

Comment: im thinking this could be made alot easier by using [googles youtube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Comment: Thank you! I just registered a Google API account, do you know how I can achieve this using YouTube API then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a youtube search i used on an old site of mine using the youtube api from google

```
<?php
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
  require_once ('video/Google_Client.php');
  require_once ('video/Google_YouTubeService.php');

  /* Set $DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
  Google APIs Console <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
  Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  $youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

  try {
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_POST['query'],
      'maxResults' => '48',
    ));

    $videos = '';
    $channels = '';

    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .=  $searchResult;


          break;

       }
    }

   } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }


echo print_r($videos);
?>
```

i used a form to post a search query(notice the $_POST['search'] variable, which will be the string to search for, in your case the movie name)

Comment: Thank you! My code is similar I simply edited the max results to 1 to get the first video. Works great!